# Jquery validate rule - how to require an option to be selected before validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, selected

I want some input data to be validated only if specific option in a dropdown is selected. For radiobutton this is done with such rule:

`required : "#radioId:checked"`

How can this be done for an option in dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

If memoery serves, you can have a callback that returns whether the option you want to see selected is selected:

```
required: function(element) {
    return $("#selectID>option:selected").val() == 18;//or whatever value you require
  }
```

Comment: I've found even simpler solution: required: "#option1Id:selected"

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to write your own selector:

```
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
    myselector: function (e)
    {
        return $(e).val() == 'mine';
    }
});
```

Selector:

```
required : '#test:myselector'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the depends checker with something like:

```
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
 <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="inputBox" />

----------------------in your rules do---------------------

 inputBox: {
   depends: function (elt) {
     return $('#selectBox').val() === "option1"; 
     // option1 being the targeted option here
   }
 }
```